# Force push a recipe to the end of run_list in CHEF?

Tags: chef-infra, devops

Is there is a way to enforce a recipe to run as the last one, no matter where is it placed in the runlist ?

For example, If I am having a recipe say cookbook_y:post and the expanded runlist is x1::x2 y1::y2 cookbook_y::post z1::z2, I want to modify the expanded runlist in during run time (from a recipe, most likely in cookbook_y::post) and push its execution to the end.

In sort I want to dynamically achieve this during the client run x1::x2 y1::y2 z1::z2 cookbook_y::post

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that? Is it because it is performing some task on basis of chef run completion?

Comment: Yes, there are certain tests  that needs to run after the convergance. And so it should be the last one.

Comment: converting the recipe to Chef Handler will help in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really something Chef supports. You can use tricks with delayed notifications like this:

```
package 'foo' do
  action :nothing
  delayed_action :install
end
```

But that has to be on each resource and there is no way to order between different delayed notifications (they happen in the order scheduled) so you can end up with the problem of "I need this to be last-iesr than the last thing" and we don't solve that problem for you.

Comment: Thank you @coderanger. If this can't be achieved dynamically can I enforce a policy to add a specific cookbook at the end of runlist (for all my nodes)? My objective is to make sure that this cookbook runs last in all my nodes. I can ask the organization to follow the principle but I dont want to rely on a honor based system. People forget!

Comment: No, we don't have a system for that. The better approach is to fix whatever code currently needs to run last to be correctly convergent instead but that can be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If that recipe, which you want to move in the last of chef-client run, has to perform tasks after convergence then you might like to look on Chef handlers.

- https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html
- https://docs.chef.io/resource_chef_handler.html

Converting that recipe to handler library will ensure that the specific snippet of code would be called after the convergence only. As you may be knowing, that chef calls handlers at the end of chef run.

Comment: Handlers run at the end but cannot use the Chef recipe DSL

Comment: yes, but if the recipe concerned don't have much Chef DSL then converting it ruby library(handler) would help.

Comment: Depends on the task but it would have to be a very special case for that to make sense :)